# get array in sorted order

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have made array of object that is passed to table. The table has ui-sortable

```
<table class="table table-hover">  
<tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
  <tr ng-repeat="f in building.floors" ng-click="events.goToFloor(f.id)">
    <td>{{f.id}}</td>
    <td>{{f.level + building.minimumFloor}}</td>
    <td><button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="events.removeFloor(f.id);$event.stopPropagation();">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now using

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
        update: function(e, ui) {
            var i : number = 0;
            $scope.building.floors.forEach(f => {  
                alert(f.level);   
                f.level = i;
                i++;
            });
        }
    };
```

I want to change the level value to be in new order but I still get foreach order of pre sorted. How can i iterate through array in new order (after sorting) ?

EDIT:

I use these libs:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>        
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/master/src/sortable.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>     

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>         
    <script src="scripts/fabricjs_viewport.js"></script>
```

EDIT2:

when ia add ng-model to tbody with ui-sortable option i cannot swap last element and if I do ... there is strange behavior

```
<tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="floors">
  <tr ng-repeat="f in floors" ng-click="events.goToFloor(f.id)">
    <td>{{f.id}}</td>
    <td>{{f.level}}</td>
    <td><button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="events.removeFloor(f.id);$event.stopPropagation();">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you're missing the ng-model

---

Apply the directive to your form elements:

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="items">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

Developing Notes:

ng-model is required, so that the directive knows which model to update.
ui-sortable element should only contain one ng-repeat and not any other elements (above or below).

Otherwise the index matching of the generated DOM elements and the ng-model's items will break.

In other words: The items of ng-model must match the indexes of the generated DOM elements.

Filters that manipulate the model (like filter, orderBy, limitTo,...) should be applied in the controller instead of the ng-repeat (refer to the provided examples).

This is the preferred way since it:

- is performance wise better reduces the chance of code duplication
- is suggested by the angularJS team
- it does not break the matching of the generated DOM elements and the ng-model's items

ui-sortable lists containing many 'types' of items can be implemented by using dynamic template loading with ng-include or a loader directive, to determine how each model item should be rendered. Also take a look at the Tree with dynamic template example.

---

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable#usage

Comment: Adding ng-model didn't help (at least I had to do one more thing). The link you provided gave events and their order. Had to replace update with stop in sortableOptions